# UILabel in different subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, nsarray, uilabel

I'm creating my first app. It will be a catalog of products, that you can scroll through.
I created a `UIScrollView` with a width of 960 (320*3) and added a `UIPageControl`. Inside it I added 3 different view, each of them represents one of my products - with all the information I need - name, image, description, price, etc..

I can see the views move, and so I've set the first product with `UILabel` classes and `UIImageView`. I was wondering if it is possible to use `NSArray` and set the `UILabel`'s `text` property and `imageNamed` in the next view as the user switches to it.

My problem is that each view has a different `UILabel` element.

Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: I know this was not a question from you but you **cannot** use the `+imageNamed:` class method if you are working with images which are **not** in the application bundle.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question? I'm having trouble to understand what you are looking for.
If your question is "can I use an NSArray to store the informations I am displaying on the views?" the response is of course you can. But I doubt that's what you are asking for.

Comment: I have different subviews and I want to display information inside them using NSArray. how can I link labels in different subviews to the same NSArray?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use a NSArray to store the data for each of your views. I would suggest first creating a simple object with the properties labelText and imageName;

Then you can create a NSArray of your custom object like this:

```
MyObject obj1 = [MyObject new];
obj1.labelText = @"My Text 1";
obj1.imageName = @"My Image 1";

//Other objects..

then

NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
```

Then When you switch pages simply do this:

```
MyObject *myPageInfo = [myArray objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
myLabel.text = myPageInfo.labelText;
mylabel.imageName = myPageInfo.imageName;
```

Hope that helps.